# Thread synchronized block with Class itself

Tags: java, multithreading

I thought that following usage is to create a synchronized-block because `ThreadMyClass.class` is unique.
But When I have created a heavy traffic with multiple Threads trying to access `get()` method, I have found out that many inconsistent states were created.
So why threads are not synchronized with `ThreadMyClass.class` instance?

```
public ThreadMyClass {


 public Object  get(){

  synchronized (ThreadMyClass.class) {
    //get object return 
  }

 }
}


public static final  Object lock = new Object();
```

When I have changed `ThreadMyClass.class` with `lock` object , everything is working fine.

**updated: 
here is my full code portion** instance creation block is invoked more than one time.

```
   public static XmppInterface getInstance() throws XMPPException {
      if (instance == null) {
         synchronized (XmppInterface.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
              //create an instance
            }
         }
      }
      return instance;
   }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code. If I am not mistaken, your `get`-implementation should be equivalent to `public static synchronized Object get(){/* get object return */}`. Maybe the cause for the incosistencies is in code you do not show? Can't you show a full minimal working example that exhibits the problems, i.e., add the thread-creation, the calls to `get` and a minimal `get`-implementation?

Comment: Another reason for not using the class object as a lock, other classes could try to sync on it. Potential for deadlocks and delays.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce an inconsistent state. Your code looks fine to me, but maybe I just don't see the error. However, since you seem to be trying to enforce the Singleton-property on `XmppInterface`, you could also solve this using an enum: Have a look at Item 3 in Effective Java: http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf

Comment: this code does not run directly on JVM, it runs on a weblogic 12c. So I think there should be some life trick about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you were synchronizing over the `class`, not its instance, which was tantamount to having a `static synchronized` method.

To synchronize over the instance of your class you can use a `synchronized` instance method.

Otherwise, synchronizing over an `Object` used for a lock will synchronize on that `Object` only, leaving the rest of your static and instance methods "free" from the synchronization strategy in place.

Comment: according to the web site, my usage shoul be correct. I am using ClassLevel locking. http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/08/thread-synchronization-object-level-locking-and-class-level-locking/

Comment: @mmc18 had a quick look at the article. It basically underlines the difference between what it calls "object level locking" (which seems to include both object locking and instance locking) and class level locking. There are also other idioms unspoken of there, such as using an actual `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`, etc. It all depends on the context and what you want to achieve, really.